# Mongoose connection automatically shared in Express.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm developing a RESTful API using Express.js and Mongodb (and the mongoose module for accessing to the db with Schemas).
I was looking for the best way of sharing the connection to the Mongo database across the entire Express app in order to not to have a new connection for every single request (It's advised by the web and by other answers on Stackoverflow). 
I have read about different solutions and I decided to make a try using this architecture:

In **server.js** (main app file) I have something like this:

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var logger =  require("morgan");
var configuration = require("./configuration.js");
var fs = require("fs");
var HTTPresponses = require("./responses.js"); 
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

require("./models/user_model.js");

var Users = mongoose.model("Users");

//Connect to Db 
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1/test");

//Rest of the code here
```

As you can see I create a new connection to the database using mongoose and then I require  user_module that is something like this:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name : {type: String},
    surname : {type: String},
    username : {type: String, unique: true, required: true}     
    }

,{
    collection : "Users"
});

mongoose.model("Users", UserSchema);
```

This way the UserSchema is compiled directly in the mongoose object.

And now is the **Question**: I noticed that every model compiled in server.js and the connection to the db are available in every middleware that I use just requiring the mongoose module"... "**Why does it work?**"

So... if I have a middleware that needs to access to the db the only thing I have to do is to require the moongose module and retreive models I need simply calling:

```
var MY_MODEL = mongoose.model("NAME_OF_THE_MODEL_COMPILED_in_serve.js");
```

I think this is a good thing but I have no idea about the why it is working.
I mean... I have read tons of Questions and Answers talking about the best way to obtain this result but I have never read about this way.

I have also read the documentation about Express.js ... but nothing.

Is it maybe related with the caching system of Express ?

Is it a safe way to share a database connection across the Express App?

Thanks in advance,

Luca

Comment: When you require a module in node.js, the module only executes once, then the response from it is cached and returned every time you require it after that. So, every time you `require('mongoose')`, you're getting the same mongoose that you've already connected to your database and attached models to.

Comment: But...is this a good way for sharing Models and connection to the database?

Comment: Yes. I posted that as a comment because i assumed there must be a duplicate, but I can't find one. Most that cover this topic are directly asking about the documentation that explains this functionality, I can't find one that skipped the documentation like this question has.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As `server.js` is the main entry point of your application, that is the first place where node sees the `mongoose` module required.

Any update to the `mongoose` module instance is reflected in that particular instance.

For example, if you require `mongoose` in your `server.js` file and in your `user.js` model file, you will only make changes to the same `mongoose` object.

This is due to the way CommonJS modules are cached throughout an application.

If you would like to read more about the way modules are being cached, I recommend the following two sources:

- [NodeJS Official Docs - Modules Caching](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching)
- [CommonJS Modules Wiki](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1)

Comment: Thank you; because I have followed this guide :"Node.js, MongoDb and Angular.js" by Brad Dayley .. but it does not talk about this "little" detail.

Comment: This means that if you define more than one connection in `server.js`, requiring mongoose in `user.js` would always get the last defined connection. So, in a multiple database environment, it would make sense to export each  `mongoose.connect` and then require those to define a schema, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: @Gob I believe that the best idea would be to have a class DatabasesConnections that takes care about all the connections...
Then you share this class among your app.